# where put html form in Res folder and how to show this html form in webview

Tags: android, android-widget

I have html form.but i dont understand where is put this html form. how to display form in web view.Thanks in advance

```
  <Html> 
    <Head>
    <Title>
    <Title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="60%" align="center">
    <TR><TD colspan="2"><span class="style1">Post comments</span></TD>
    </TR>
    <form  action="http://www.indianexpress.com/ajax/saveComment.php" id="frmcommentmain" name="frmcommentmain" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="918703" name="storyId">
    <input type="hidden" value="172.16.24.10" name="ip_addr">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="parentcmtId">
    <TR><TD height="35">Name:</TD><TD><input type="text" name="name" tiptitle="Please enter your name">
      *</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD>Email:</TD><TD><input type="text" name="email"  tiptitle="Please enter your email">
      *</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD>Title:</TD><TD><input type="text" name="subject" tiptitle="Please enter subject">
      *</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD>Comment:</TD><TD><textarea title="Please enter your comments"  rows="6" name="comment"></textarea>
      *</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" name="checkbox">I agree to the terms of use.</TD></TR>
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan="2"><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="submit"></TD></TR>
    </form>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have read many articles but I did not get answer for putting html form.Many articles described load data from url in webview but i want to load form in webview.

Comment: String str = "<html>....</html>"; webview.loadData(str,"text/html","UTF-8");

Answer (score 2):

Indeed place your html page in the assets folder.
For showing the webpage use a `WebView`

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the HTML content in a file in the assets folder in your Android project. You should then be able to read the file from your code and load it into a Webview.

Comment: I would certainly refrain from storing the HTML content as a string in your code. It would bloat your code for no real reason. Also storing in the assets makes it a lot more maintainable.